# Why does this cycles render have grainy edges?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I am trying to simulate a camera calibration procedure using Blender and for this reason I am trying to generate images of a checkerboard pattern to use in the calibration algorithm. After rendering I noticed two problems (as you can see in the attached image):

- The straight lines are "pixelated"
- The angles of the squares in the pattern are not touching

Complete view:

[image: Complete view]

The problem:

[image: Zoomed view]

I am rendering with cycles at 1600x1200 resolution, the lens used is a perspective lens. The checkerboard is generated using the materials checkerboard option and roughness is set to 0.

Comment: How many samples are you using? with an emission shader, I got this result at around the 2nd sample, but after 5 samples the noise artefacts were gone.

Comment: Do you mean the sampling in the global scene settings? if yes I am using 10 samples. I am using a Diffuse BSDF shader with a light source behind my cameras (more faithful simulation perhaps?). An Emission  shader gave some artifacts but less than the diffuse shader. I then reduced the number of samples to 1 and it gave a perfect result (weird?). does this have any draw backs?

Comment: If you just want to test for reading the chessboard and not anything optical or light related, then the more perfect the result, the better I would assume (?). The thing with rendering engines like cycles, is that they perform all kinds of optimization, denoising and filtering processes with each sample - which improve complex scenes and give better results while reducing rendering times. This could go contrary to what you're trying to achieve, which is simply to render out a perfect chessboard. A single sample doesn't give the engine time to adaptively filter out the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes sense. I think in this case that the high frequency of the edges/corners is somehow washed out by the filtering algorithms and thus showing a "smoother" and thus pixelated gradient which is not desired in my case.

Comment: You should model the chessboard (nxn squares in the same model object), use two materials set alternatively to each square. This will avoid the approximation as it will follow the vertex model (so no checker texture optimizations).

Comment: @lemon I will try that as well depending on how much time I can spend on it at least for educational purposes, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's quick but needs some little knowledge about blender to do it quickly. Hope that helps : [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2685" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2685/)

Comment: Also 10 samples is way to low, that may be causing an issue there too

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I can confirm that, although the final result will show a smooth gradient between black and white (I tested for 250 samples)

Comment: @lemon Thank you I didn't know it was that simple, I need some practice apparently

Comment: @lemon That will make no difference. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hDOf.png Is made with two different materials and an array modifier, yet as you can see still displays the anti-aliasing artifacts.

Comment: @David, if you use the file I have linked above, all is ok (bake with diffuse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this is an artifact from anti-aliasing.

In the *Film* section of the *Render* tab in the *Properties* panel, set the *Width* of the *Pixel Filter* all the way down (0.01). That in essence turns off the anti-aliasing.
[image: anti-aliasing setting]

---

If you are using a shadeless material (*Emission* shader) so noise is not a problem, then there is another way to remove the anti-aliasing.
Set the samples to **one**.
With only one sample there are not enough samples for the anti-aliasing algorithms to work, because there is only one.